# My MongoDB Atlas Operations graph has doubled in the last few hours. How do I go about debugging this?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I noticed this graph in my MongoDB Atlas dashboard:

[image]

I'm not sure what is causing the increased Disk IOPS and Operations counts... Can I use the oplog to figure out what is causing this massive increase in operations?

Comment: What cluster do you have in MongoDB Atlas?

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan I have an M10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My MongoDB Atlas Operations graph has doubled in the last few hours.
>   How do I go about debugging this?

As per MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/tutorial/monitoring-integrations/) You can use a third-party application to view and analyze [performance metrics](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/monitor-cluster-metrics/#monitor-cluster-metrics) that Atlas collects about your cluster.

At this time, you can either build a monitoring integration using the Atlas API or integrate Atlas with [Datadog](https://www.datadoghq.com/).

***Build Monitoring Integrations with Atlas API***

You can build a monitoring integration using the Atlas [API monitoring and logs endpoints](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/api/monitoring-and-logs/).

***Integrate Atlas with Datadog***

You can configure Atlas to send metric data about your project to your [Datadog](https://www.datadoghq.com/) dashboards.

> **Note:** Datadog integration is only available on M10+ clusters.

For further your ref [here](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/monitoring-integration-mongodb-atlas-datadog)